# override font face and size

Tags: html, css, font-face, font-size

I have an admin panel that my users are creating the content.
It has an editor where they can select font size like

```
<span style="font-size: x-small;">text</span>
```

What I want to achieve is to override the font style while getting the data from the db.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### CSS:

```css
span {
  font-size: 12px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the css style rule "font-family" so:

```
<span style="font-size: x-small; font-family: Verdana, sans-serif">text</span>
```

It's important to keep in mind that browser will apply first font is available, so in this case first Verdana, if there's not it will chose default "sans-serif" font.
font-family it's css equivalent of html "font-face" attrib.